Typing of object with the same keys but different types of their values
I have a set of JSON files that store source data. There is one file for a language and all of them have the same keys but different types of values. It's like this:
// source-en.json
{
  "action": ["change", "check"],
  "device": ["coil", "relay"],
}

// source-pl.json
{
  "action": ["wymienić", "sprawdzić"],
  "device": [
    {
      "gender": "f",
      "singular": "cewkę",
      "plural": "cewki"
    },
    {
      "gender": "m",
      "singular": "przekaźnik",
      "plural": "przekaźniki"
    }
  ]
}

So, I could describe them with the interfaces:
interface SourceEn {
  action: string[],
  device: string[],
}

interface SourcePl {
  action: string[],
  device: NounForms[],
}

interface NounForms {
  gender: 'm' | 'f' | 'n' | 'pl';
  singular: string;
  plural: string;
}

Now, I have the set of classes that consume the data: EnConsumer, PlConsumer... that inherit from the BaseConsumer. BaseConsumer knows how to get the source files and turn JSON into actual data while concrete classes know how to deal with language-specific differences. So, the BaseConsumer looks like this:
type Source = SourceEn | SourcePl;

class BaseConsumer<T extends Source> {
  public readonly action: Collection<ArrayItem<T['action']>>;
  public readonly device: Collection<ArrayItem<T['device']>>;

  public constructor(language: Language) {
    const data = this.getData(language);
    this.action = new Collection(data.action);
    this.device = new Collection(data.device);
  }
  
  protected getData(language: Language): T {...}
}

class Collection<T> {
  public constructor(private store: T[]) {}
}

type ArrayItem<A extends unknown[]> = A extends (infer E)[] ? E : never;

enum Language {
  EN = 'en',
  PL = 'pl',
}

But it doesn't work. Specifically, this.device = new Collection(data.device); line gives two errors:

data.device:


Argument of type string[] | NounForms[] is not assignable to parameter of type string[] 
Type NounForms[] is not assignable to type string[] 
Type NounForms is not assignable to type string


this.device:


Type Collection<string> is not assignable to type Collection<Source['device']> 
Type string is not assignable to type Source['device']

Problems stems from the fact that T extends Source represents an union of SourceEn and SourcePl. But with class ConsumerPl extends BaseConsumer<SourcePl> the ConsumerPl class should know which of the interfaces actually applies and which types should apply to the respective fields.
I don't know how to express it in TypeScript. I don't want to be too explicit because today it supports English and Polish but tomorrow it could be Klingon and Quenya too. So verbose conditional types are not valid solution. So how can I make the BaseConsumer correctly generic?

Is there a reason you don't just start with { [key: string]: (string | NounForms)[] }?

@jonrsharpe: yes, I have specific JSON files I want to type. They have the same set of keys that represent various parts of a sentence and Consumers use those fixed parts to actually compose this sentence. Of course, different languages have different grammar so that the types of data under the keys differ.

@jcalz: I added it both here and in the playground: https://tsplay.dev/mb2B8m . As you can see, I Collection accepts non-array actually and in BaseConsumer I use ArrayType to un-array the type from Source's key

In your getData method, are you actually unsure of which type you're returning? As in either SourceEn or SourcePl?

My suggestion would be to change your generic so it maps from language name to the underlying source data type (so string and not string[]), as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz: yes, sorry, my bad. Corrected that, both here and in https://tsplay.dev/N97PoW . ArrayItem is used to get array's type (string[] => string). Nevertheless, I've seen your latest suggestion and I'm yet to parse that. For example, I don't know why there is number in { [K in keyof T]: T[K][number] }? I'll analyze it later today, though. Thanks for thorough reply :)

@Andrew: I know what is returned because it's chosen based on the language parameter. Issue is I have trouble expressing it in TypeScript. Using T extends Source means I'm referencing a union so every key has type of union of types of all the members of the union. @jcalz already provided a promising suggestion but I'm yet to analyze it and I'm already wondering if it could be done in easier way :)

But do you know in advance if it will be a NounForms object or a SourceEn object ahead of time? Either way, it seemed like you have an extra array in there somewhere in your types. Check out the answer I added below. I'll edit it to include a ts playground. There's no errors, but I had to make the array depth match and I'm not sure which one is right... either making the type an array of arrays, or making the constructor type without the array.

"I'm already wondering if it could be done in easier way" ?? With the types you gave, I'd say "no" and that your ArrayItem is less "easy" than using number (Array<T>[number] is T, which I'd happily explain if I end up writing an answer post.)  If I'm allowed to change your underlying types so that we don't need to dissect arrays, then I'd write it like this, and you could always map to a version with arrays just like I mapped to a version with Collection. Let me know when you're done analyzing my suggestion and how you'd like to proceed.

@jcalz: Unfortunately, the types of Source* are tied to the data structure and cannot be changed. The code from your first comment works, of course. However, I don't fully understand how. First, in type ToBaseSource<T extends Record<keyof T, any[]>> I don't understand how it's possible that T extends itself in keyof T. Second, I think that {[K in keyof T]: T[K][number]} means "object with keys from T and values of type of T's key. But why [number] if both SourcePl and SourceEn have keys` values of array types? Please, issue an answer to explain.

The minimum changes to resolve your errors are the following:
type ArrayItem<A extends unknown[]> = A[number];

class BaseConsumer<T extends Source> {
    public readonly action: Collection<ArrayItem<T['action']>>;
    public readonly device: Collection<ArrayItem<T['device']>>;

    public constructor(language: Language) {
        const data = this.getData(language);
        this.action = new Collection<ArrayItem<T['action']>>(data.action);
        this.device = new Collection<ArrayItem<T['device']>>(data.device);
    }

    protected getData(language: Language): T { return null! }
}

I've changed ArrayItem from your conditional type to a simpler indexed access type.  An array of type Array<X> has a numeric index signature of type {[k: number]: X}, because TypeScript models arrays as having elements at numeric keys.  So if you have a string[] and index into it with a numeric key, you'll get a string.  Your conditional type is conceptually the same, but generic conditional types are much harder for the compiler to reason about than generic indexed access types.
I've also manually specified the generic type argument to Collection to be the corresponding generic type. If you don't do that then the compiler tries to infer that type, and it ends up widening data from T to its constraint Source, and the union is no longer known to correspond to the type of this.action and this.device. TypeScript widening generic values to their constraints is a common pitfall, and one way to avoid that is to manually specify the generic type arguments to functions.

That's all well and good, but you don't get the generic behavior you need out of BaseConsumer.  Since the constructor argument is the non-generic Language, you get a useless BaseConsumer<Source> out of it:
const pl = new BaseConsumer(Language.PL)
//const pl: BaseConsumer<Source>
pl.device
// ^? (property) BaseConsumer<Source>.device: Collection<string | NounForms>

That's not what you want.  The type of pl.device should be Collection<NounForms>, right?  So we need a different approach.

In order for this to work, we should make BaseConsumer<L> generic in the type L of the language constructor argument, and then use a mapping type to connect those language names to the corresponding action and device data types, without any arrays to get in the way.  That is, we could use a mapping like
interface LanguageSourceMap {
    en: {
        action: string,
        device: string,
    },
    pl: {
        action: string,
        device: NounForms,
    }
}

and then, for example, LanguageSourceMap[L]['action'] is the action data type for language L (using indexed access types to drill down into the key and subkey of LanguageSourceMap).
Once we have that we can write BaseConsumer as:
class BaseConsumer<L extends Language> {
    public readonly action: Collection<LanguageSourceMap[L]['action']>;
    public readonly device: Collection<LanguageSourceMap[L]['device']>;

    public constructor(language: L) {
        const data = this.getData(language);
        this.action = new Collection(data.action);
        this.device = new Collection(data.device);
    }

    protected getData(language: Language):
        { [K in keyof LanguageSourceMap[L]]:
            LanguageSourceMap[L][K][] } { return null! }
}

which works well because now getData() returns a mapped type over LanguageSourceMap[L], and indexing into that with action or device gives exactly the indexed access type we have for this.action and this.device.  The compiler is much happier concluding things about LanguageSourceMap[L][K][] where L extends Language and K extends keyof LanguageSourceMap[K], than it is about T extends Source.  Mapped types and indexed access types are just easier for the compiler to reason about than unions and conditional types. See microsoft/TypeScript#47109 for the basis for this approach, where we start with a base mapping type like LanguageSourceMap and express things in terms of generic indices into that type and into mapped types over that type.
Let's make sure new BaseConsumer behaves the way we want:
const pl = new BaseConsumer(Language.PL)
// const pl: BaseConsumer<Language.PL>
pl.device
// ^? (property) BaseConsumer<Language.PL>.device: Collection<NounForms>

Looks good.

We're almost done. The only thing is that we don't want to write LanguageSourceMap out manually, when you've already got your SourceEn and SourcePl types.  So let's rewrite LanguageSourceMap so it consumes those explicitly:
type ToBaseSource<T extends Record<keyof T, any[]>> =
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K][number] };

interface LanguageSourceMap {
    [Language.EN]: ToBaseSource<SourceEn>;
    [Language.PL]: ToBaseSource<SourcePl>;
}

Here ToBaseSource<T> accepts any T whose properties are all arrays (it uses a recursive constraint, T extends Record<keyof T, any[]>. Constraints like X extends Record<keyof X, Y> are useful to constrain the value type of properties without caring about the key type), and for each array property T[K] it uses a number indexed access to get the array element type. This is the same as the simplified ArrayItem mapped over the properties of t.
And now we're done. The LanguageSourceMap here is equivalent to the manual one written out above.

Note that all of this would be simpler if you started with LanguageSourceMap and computed SourceEn and SourePl in terms of it. But it's not that way and apparently you can't control those types. So this the best I can suggest.
Playground link to code

Thanks a lot. After you pointed it out it's obvious that an array can be expressed as an object with numeric keys - after all, typeof new Array() === 'object'. I wasn't aware of recursive constraints too, so thanks again.
I was able to simplify it a bit after all. 1: the keys of Source* are the same so I made an enum for them and it replaced keyof T in ToBaseSource. 2: I ditched the LanguageSourceMap[L] in favor of ToBaseSource<SourcePl> - I think it would reduce the number of things to remember of when adding a new language. See the changes: https://tsplay.dev/m3dxyW

This works, but it's difficult to tell exactly what you're looking for without seeing your getData method.
interface SourceEn {
    action: string[],
    device: string[],
}

interface SourcePl {
    action: string[],
    device: NounForms[],
}

interface NounForms {
    gender: 'm' | 'f' | 'n' | 'pl';
    singular: string;
    plural: string;
}

type Source = SourceEn | SourcePl;

class Collection<T> {
  public constructor(private store: T) {} // Add the array back in here if that's your intention, but then use the commented out return value below.
}

type ArrayItem<A extends unknown[]> = A extends (infer E)[] ? E : never;

enum Language {
  EN = 'en',
  PL = 'pl',
}

class BaseConsumer<T extends Source> {

    public readonly action: Collection<T['action']>;
    public readonly device: Collection<T['device']>;

    public constructor(language: Language) {
        const data: T = this.getData(language)
        // this.action = new Collection<typeof data.action>([data.action]); Either this one if you want an array of arrays.
        this.action = new Collection<typeof data.action>(data.action); // Or this one, but then I removed the array from your Collection class.
        this.device = new Collection<typeof data.device>(data.device);
    }

    protected getData(language: Language): T { return null! as T }
}

If you want an array of arrays, then use the return value that's commented out, with perhaps a method that checks whether or not it's an array of the proper depth to always return it in the form that you want, otherwise remove the array from the Collection class.
Playground

Sorry, can't get it into order. Either way, I end up with new BaseConsumer<SourceEn>(Language.EN).device typed as Collection<string[]> while it should be Collection<string>. It matters as Collection has methods for getting one of the items in store: T[] that return T. If I have store: T I'd have to dissect an array under T. Even typing the Collection with T and store: T is wrong as it allows non-array types. Collection<T extends any[]> would be better but why if we can express it simpler with just allowing any type with Collection<T> and store: T[]`
